# a long option whose "val" happens to be `0`?

Tags: c, glibc, getopt

From [GNU C library manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Option-Example.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>

/* Flag set by ‘--verbose’. */
static int verbose_flag;

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int c;

  while (1)
    {
      static struct option long_options[] =
        {
          /* These options set a flag. */
          {"verbose", no_argument,       &verbose_flag, 1},
          {"brief",   no_argument,       &verbose_flag, 0},
          /* These options don’t set a flag.
             We distinguish them by their indices. */
          {"add",     no_argument,       0, 'a'},
          {"append",  no_argument,       0, 'b'},
          {"delete",  required_argument, 0, 'd'},
          {"create",  required_argument, 0, 'c'},
          {"file",    required_argument, 0, 'f'},
          {0, 0, 0, 0}
        };
      /* getopt_long stores the option index here. */
      int option_index = 0;

      c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "abc:d:f:",
                       long_options, &option_index);

      /* Detect the end of the options. */
      if (c == -1)
        break;

      switch (c)
        {
        case 0:
          /* If this option set a flag, do nothing else now. */
          if (long_options[option_index].flag != 0)
            break;
          printf ("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);
          if (optarg)
            printf (" with arg %s", optarg);
          printf ("\n");
          break;

        case 'a':
          puts ("option -a\n");
          break;
```

What kind of option will make the program reach inside `case 0` and

```
printf("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);
```

Is it a long option whose flag is not set, or a long option whose "val" happens to be `0`?

What kind of option does " {0, 0, 0, 0}" specify?

Comment: What's the difference between reading the documentation and reading answers?

Comment: @alk this is easier to find by google...

Answer (score 1):

If the option sets a flag, i.e., `.flag` is *not* a null pointer, [`getopt_long()` returns `0`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html#Getopt-Long-Options):

> If flag is not a null pointer, that means this option should just set
>   a flag in the program. The flag is a variable of type int that you
>   define. Put the address of the flag in the flag field. Put in the val
>   field the value you would like this option to store in the flag. In
>   this case, getopt_long returns 0.

The example code does nothing here with an option that only sets a flag; this possibility is handled later in the [example program](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Option-Example.html#Getopt-Long-Option-Example):

```
/* Instead of reporting ‘--verbose’
     and ‘--brief’ as they are encountered,
     we report the final status resulting from them. */
  if (verbose_flag)
    puts ("verbose flag is set");
```

`{0, 0, 0, 0}` is merely a sentinel since the array of `option` structures must be terminated "with an element containing all zeros."

### Edit:

The all-zero (`{ 0, 0, 0, 0 }`) element is used internally in `getopt_long()` to determine when the end of the array of `option` structures has been reached. When this occurs, a value of `-1` is returned. The `while(1)` loop in the example code checks for this first, and terminates the loop in this case:

```
/* Detect the end of the options. */
      if (c == -1)
        break;
```

> What kind of option will make the program reach inside `case 0` and `printf("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);`?

If the `.val` field of the option happens to contain `0`, then a `.flag` that is a null pointer will cause `getopt_long()` to return this value (`0`). The code following the first `if` statement in `case 0` checks for this possibility. This is probably meant to illustrate in this example code that a return value of `0` from `getopt_long()` by itself may not indicate that a flag was set. But this is a special case, and no elements of the array in the example will cause the `printf()` statement to be reached. This may even be considered a degenerate case; it would probably be best to avoid using `0` in the `.val` field of an option, and to avoid specifying numeric values here altogether in favor of the convention of using character constants as done in the example. If you adopt this convention, a value of `'\0'` in the `.val` field would be needed to trigger this behavior.

Comment: Thanks, (1) Why "The last element of the array has to be filled with zeros"? (2) Does the while loop in the example have an iteration for the all zero element? If yes, what does `getopt_long` do with the all zero element? (3) In the example, what kind of option can  reach both inside `case 0` (i.e. `getopt_long` returns `0`) and `printf("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);` (i.e. `long_options[option_index].flag` is `0`?

Comment: Does `getopt_long` ever process the all zero element? How does `while (1)`  terminate?

Comment: @Tim-- my last comment was poorly worded; see my update.

Answer (score 1):

When the `flag` field in a `struct option` is non-NULL, `getopt_long` will return 0 for that option and the value of the `val` field is stored at the address given in `flag`.

So in the example above, when the "verbose" option is given, `getopt_long` will return 0 and `verbose_flag` is set to 1.  Similarly for the "brief" option, `getopt_long` will return 0 and `verbose_flag` is set to 0.

The option at the end of the array with all fields set to zero is a flag indicating the end of the list of options, used instead of passing in the length of the array.  Because the all zero element is just an end-of-array indicator and not a true option, there is no case needed to handle it.

From the [man page for `getopt_long`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt):

> `longopts` is a pointer to the first element of an array of `struct option` declared in  as
>
> ```
> struct option {
>     const char *name;
>     int         has_arg;
>     int        *flag;
>     int         val;
> };
> ```
>
> The meanings of the different fields are:
>
> *name*
>
> is the name of the long option.
>
> *has_arg*
>
> is: `no_argument` (or 0) if the option does not take an argument; 
>   `required_argument` (or 1) if the option requires an argument; or
>   `optional_argument` (or 2) if the option takes an optional argument.
>
> *flag*
>
> specifies how results are returned for a long option. If flag is NULL,
>   then getopt_long() returns val. (For example, the calling program may
>   set val to the equivalent short option character.) **Otherwise,
>   getopt_long() returns 0, and flag points to a variable which is set to
>   val if the option is found, but left unchanged if the option is not
>   found.**
>
> *val*
>
> is the value to return, or to load into the variable pointed to by
>   flag.
>
> **The last element of the array has to be filled with zeros.**

As to what kind of option would go past the `break` and call `printf` in `case 0:`,  an option with 0 (or NULL) for `flag`, 0 for `val`, and a non-null `name` would land here, i.e. `{ "other_option", required_argument, 0, 0 }`.  There's no option in the list like this so that code would not be executed, however it's probably included anyway as a safety check against future code that might do something like that.

Comment: The "real" docs are here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html not spoiled by spawn and orderly maintained.

Comment: Thanks, (1) Why "The last element of the array has to be filled with zeros"? (2) Does the while loop in the example have an iteration for the all zero element? If yes, what does `getopt_long` do with the all zero element? (3) In the example, what kind of option can  reach both inside `case 0` (i.e. `getopt_long` returns `0`) and `printf("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);` (i.e. `long_options[option_index].flag` is `0`?

Comment: Thanks. "Because the all zero element is just an end-of-array indicator and not a true option, there is no case needed to handle it." When does `getopt_long` return `-1`? When does the `while(1)` loop terminate?

Comment: @Tim `getopt_long` returns -1 when all options have been processed.  The code above calls `break` in that situation, which is what gets out of the `while (1)` loop.